# Ellipsize "END" doesn't work properly

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a TextView programmatically in this way:

```
TextView textDescription = new TextView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsDesc = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 25);
layoutParamsDesc.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
textDescription.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsDesc);
textDescription.setText("Lengthy text in TextView");
linearLayoutDatos.addView(textDescription);
textDescription.setEllipsize (TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
textDescription.setMaxLines(1);
textDescription.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
```

However, no "three dots" are displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `textDescription.setMaxLines(1);` but the proper usage for it to work is like below:

For single line

```
textDescription.setSingleLine(true);
```

For multiple lines (more than 1)

```
textDescription.setMaxLines(2);
```

An the other thing is, write this line after you do all your settings with textDescription.

```
linearLayoutDatos.addView(textDescription);
```

So in the end it will be like this:

```
TextView textDescription = new TextView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsDesc = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 25);
layoutParamsDesc.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
textDescription.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsDesc);
textDescription.setText("Lengthy text in TextView");
textDescription.setEllipsize (TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
textDescription.setSingleLine(true);
textDescription.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
linearLayoutDatos.addView(textDescription);
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. It doesn't even "ellipsize" the text. If I add "textDescription.setWidth(0)" the text is truncated, but "three dots" are not added.

Answer (score 0):

Add `textDescription.setSingleLine()`

Answer (score 0):

You must set a `maxLength` property of the `TextView`. You can do that like this:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this); 
int maxLength = 25;
InputFilter[] filterArray = new InputFilter[1];
filterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
textView.setFilters(filterArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
textDescription.setEllipsize (TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
```

Comment: Can you add padding right to the textview maybe 5 dp to see if its showing the 3 dots or not.... textDescription.setPadding(0, 0, 5, 0)

Comment: I added textDescription.setPadding(0, 0, 5, 0) using "END" and "MARQUEE", but "three dots" are not displayed in any case. Padding is ok, but empty space is displayed.